# Quiz website with timer for questions using javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to ask how a quiz website works with an associated timer with each question. Since each question has a timer associated with each question and is handled at the front end, a client can change the value for these timers using developer console as these will be global variables.

Comment: I'd have to know specifically which site you're talking about, but usually that would be handled server-side. Server checks if your answer is on time by checking that server-side value.

Answer (score 1):

No. They can not edit the time. Since the time is coming from the server,  you shouldn't be able to edit it using the console. If you are able to edit it from the console, usually the server will notice that this client is off sync and try to bring it back on sync. If it does neither, it's probably bad programming

Answer (score 1):

Use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), which will put your variables inside the function and make them non-global:

```
(function(){
    // Put your code in here.
})();
```

Note that while someone won't be able to change the time directly, they can still spoof different requests. You should probably keep track of time server-side.